# Using variable as shortcode parameter

Tags: shortcode

The shortcode I'm using is:

```
[survey_records id=number qid="3" aid="selected" data="answer" uid="68" session="last"]
```

I want the `id` to be variable, like:

```
[survey_records id="$variable" qid="3" aid="selected" data="answer" uid="68" session="last"]
```

How can I change the `id` parameter to a dynamic variable?

Comment: Where are you using the shortcode?

Comment: Is this your own custom shortcode?  If so, it would be helpful to include the shortcode function in your question.

Comment: Where/how would the variable be get its value?

Comment: its shortcode from plugin and i need change id from number to variable

Comment: I believe to do what you're asking you'd have to, instead of dropping the shortcode into the content, add it via code so that you can inject the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than dropping the shortcode into the content the way you normally would, you'd instead need to add it via code with an `echo`.

So instead of adding `[survey_records id=number qid="3" aid="selected" data="answer" uid="68" session="last"]` to the content/block editor, you'd want this instead:

```
<?php
    echo do_shortcode( '[survey_records id="' . $variable . '" qid="3" aid="selected" data="answer" uid="68" session="last"]' );
?>
```

Now, how you get that into the content, that depends on a lot of different factors.  You can use a plugin that lets you add PHP to your content, or write a meta box for posts/pages that allows you to add variables where, if they are present, will execute this sort of function... ...you can hard code it into a specific template and then add some other method of attaching the variable, etc.  Lots of ways to do it.

Comment: Good . This solution has always worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcode function behind that shortcode will need to be able to accept an argument so it can return your variable in the expected place.

If this is a custom shortcode function you wrote, you'll have to make that adjustment. If its a third party shortcode, you'll need to look at their documentation and see if its possible.

Comment: its a third party shortcode